# Can a homunculus activate my Immovable Rod?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Immovable Rod says:

> You can use an action to press the button

(DMG, p175.)

An humunculus "is a construct that acts as an extension of its creator".

Can your humunculus push the darned button on your Immovable Rod?

Comment: Are you planning to use your homunculus to trigger a deadfall suspended in mid-air?

Comment: I was going to put something about conjured animals or beasts in my [answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76597/activating-an-immovable-rod-at-a-distance#answer-76606) about the Immovable Rod, I see you got the idea anyway...

Comment: @GMJoe - Break into a castle.  Castle is 120' high, 150' moat.  That's a long way w/ iRods, hand-over-handing it.  Hours.  Instead, have Hommie fly up 120' w/ iRod #1 w/ rope, anchor it.   While I climb, Hommie flies to a point midway across the moat, 240' above the water, w/ iRod #2 and rope #2.  Hommie anchors iRod #2.  I swing across.  I figure the whole thing takes about 10 rounds.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke - conjured animals or beasts is a good idea.  I've been nervous about the "you press the button" phrasing of the iRod.  Although as someone pointed out, it also says, "you or another creature", so any conjured creature or beast capable of pushing a button ought to work.

Comment: @Jack Wow, that is much better than my solution of packing a hammock so I can take a rest part-way.

Comment: @GMJoe - the hammock has a lot of panache.  I like it.  Bring a snack and a book.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Yes

Immovable Rod

> Until you or another creature uses an action to push the button again,
>   the rod doesn’t move, even if it is defying gravity.

The Homunculus has a stat block (S 4/D 15/C 11/I 10/W 10/Ch 7).  As a construct, it is a *creature.*  It can interact with things. (Example: with it's bite it makes a *melee weapon attack*).

There is no minimum strength required to push the button listed for the item.  I see no reason to argue that it can't push the button.

---

As I read the introduction to "Monsters" in the rules, all monsters are creatures.  That makes constructs a kind of creature.

*(MM p. 6) Constructs are made, not born. {snip}  Many creatures native to the outer plane of Mechanus, such as modrons, are constructs shaped from the raw material of the plane by the will of more powerful creatures.*

Comment: Ah, good catch on "or another creature".

Answer (score 5):

Here's an image of a possibly typical homunculus:

[image]

As you can see, it generally has normal appendages, and is physically capable of interacting with things, and the Immovable Rod has no special requirements about being able to use it (i.e. you don't need a Use Magic Item check to press the button). So, under normal circumstances, your homunculus should definitely be able to activate immovable rods without any difficulty.

Comment: That picture.  That is such a . . . I'm trying to think of a word for it.  Attractive, cute, friendly.  Definitely none of those.  There's also a picture in the MM.  The new MM.  I actually recognize that pic from the MM from deep in the last century.

Comment: Jack, the one in 5e is not that much cuter... less pustulent maybe.