# Is Mordenkainen's Faithful Hound a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Firstly, is the hound even a creature? If so, does it get advantage due to being invisible, and opportunity attacks — seeing as how animated objects get opportunity attacks?

Comment: You need to treat each of these things as one question.

Comment: What gburton means is that we have a one question per post policy here. Please split your questions up and ask them seperately. And please include what game system and edition you're asking about. Also, welcome. Please take the [tour] to get an idea of how things work around here.

Comment: This is still two different questions about one thing. Could you please reduce it to one question? You can always post your other questions as other question posts.

Comment: I've just removed the second question myself, so I could reopen this. You can always access the removed text (for copying and pasting into new question posts, for example) by clicking the “edited [time]” text link at the bottom of the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

### It is probably not a creature.

The term "creature" is [not explicitly defined](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47254/what-is-the-definition-of-creature-and-is-it-used-consistently) in 5e, so we have to look to other spells and situations for analogous situations.

Spells such as Unseen Servant and Bigby's Hand create entities that have some of the properties of creatures, like HP, AC, and grappling, but they are [not creatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74639/how-does-an-unseen-servant-move/74642#74642). Likewise, while the hound can make attacks, it doesn't have other game statistics like ability scores.

On the other hand, the spell Simulacrum explicitly states that its creation is a creature:

> The duplicate is a creature, partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature.

Mordenkainen's faithful hound does not have such text, and neither do Unseen Servant or Bigby's hand.

### It does not get opportunity attacks, and advantage is probably a DM ruling.

Given that it's not a creature, the rules for opportunity attacks don't apply. Note that animated objects (from the Animate Objects spell) don't get opportunity attacks either, as you can only command them to attack on your own turn.

RAW, the invisibility rules require the attacker to be a creature, and since the hound is not, it doesn't get advantage. I think that is open for DM interpretation, however.

Comment: Re animated objects, I think the question means the ones in the Monster Manual, not the ones from *animate object*. I suspect so, because the former do seem to be full “creatures” and don't seem to have any reason to *not* get opportunity attacks.

Comment: It's true that the MM animated objects get opportunity attacks. I think that the spell is more relevant to the question, but I suppose the asker will have to clarify which one they're referring to.

Comment: For whatever it's worth [Crawford says it's not meant to be a creature](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/04/conjurer-hound/).