# What are a magic item's saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

We're building a spell that can target magical items, similar to *[mage's disjunction](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/mageSDisjunction.html)* in Pathfinder. Fifth edition has a spell that targets spells affecting objects: *dispel magic*, but nothing that directly affects magical items, as far as I can tell. If we want to target magical items, it makes sense to give magical items a save (as in 3.5/Pathfinder).

The easiest way to do this is just to give the item an arbitrary saving throw, with a bonus for rarity. Better still would be giving it a Wisdom or Constitution save.

Borrowing from Pathfinder again ([source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/)):

> *Magical Items*: Magic items always get saving throws. A magic item’s
>   Fortitude, Reflex, and Will save bonuses are equal to 2 + half its
>   caster level. An attended magic item either makes saving throws as its
>   owner or uses its own saving throw bonus, whichever is better.

Is there a similar rule in *fifth edition*? How do you determine a magic item's saves?

Note: I'm not talking about sentient magical items. I'm looking for a rule to apply to regular magical items. Sentient magical items would likely get a bonus though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can magical spells damage objects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78448/can-magical-spells-damage-objects)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No.

**RAW:**

**Only creatures make saving throws.** Unattended objects (including magic items) do not make saving throws. But most damaging spells **do not affect objects** anymore. Almost all of them only affect creatures.

Even the mighty [Disintegrate](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Disintegrate) (and it can affect objects) is ineffective on magical objects:

> This spell automatically disintegrates a Large or smaller non-magical object or a creation of magical force. If the target is a Huge or larger object or creation of force, this spell disintegrates a 10-foot-cube portion of it. A magic item is unaffected by this spell.

One damaging spell that can affect magical objects is [Meteor Swarm](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Meteor_Swarm):

> The spell damages objects in the area and ignites flammable objects that aren’t being worn or carried.

[Objects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Objects#content) have Armor Class and Hitpoints. Not saving throws. They have a "damage threshold" that works like the old 3.5 hardness.

Magic items have resistance to all damage:

> `[Comment:]` Might be worth pointing out that most magic items do have Resistance to all damage (DMG 141) since that isn't mentioned with the rest of the Object HP rules. – Erik

**Homebrewing:**

Saving throws are bound to abilities in 5e. If you were to make an item with ability scores, then it would gain saving throws. [Animated Objects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Animate%20Objects#content) for example, are treated like creatures when they are animated. They have Ability scores, so they should be able to make saves in these two abilities.

> An animated object is a construct with AC, hit points, attacks, **Strength**, and **Dexterity** determine by its size. Its **Constitution is 10** and its **Intelligence and Wisdom are 3**, and its **Charisma is 1**.

(*Nobody said they would have **great** saving throws*).

Comment: @daze413 WIP. I sometimes just click to post the answer while I am collecting the sources, to avoid any problems with a crash.

Comment: @Mindwin do you have a source for "Unattended magic items do not make saving throws." I agree with you, just want to find that stated in the rules.

Comment: @CaptainPhoenix only creatures make saving throws.

Answer (score 4):

There is no spell or effect in 5e that you could base such an effect on. *Dispel magic* has no effect on permanent magic items, it only ends spell effects (like *magic weapon*). *Antimagic field* disables magical items too, along with all other magic, but does not require a save.

Because of that, objects have no ability scores either, only creatures do:

> abilities provide a quick description of every **creature**'s physical
>   and mental characteristics (PHB 173, emphasis mine)

If you wish to create an effect that targets the magic of a permanent magic item, you will have to homebrew it from scratch.

Comment: Fair point on dispel magic. Thanks for that.

Comment: Anti-magic field would render magic items non-magical. >"Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items **become mundane**. Until the spell ends, the sphere moves with you, centered on you."

Comment: @SpacyRicochet that's still temporary though.

Comment: @SpacyRicochet Nice catch. I have updated my answer to include it.