# Can an Unseen Servant benefit from the Inspiring Leader feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, targeting, temporary-hit-points

Say a fighter with the Inspiring Leader feat is inspiring his companions, and the wizard's *unseen servant* is listening while doing their laundry. Does the servant feel inspired (i.e. gain temp hp)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Unfortunately, it will not

The [Inspiring Leader feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/inspiring-leader) (PHB, 167) requires you to select creatures:

> ...choose up to six friendly creatures...

But an *[unseen servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant)* (PHB, 284) is not a creature, it is a force:

> This spell creates an invisible, mindless, shapeless, Medium force...

Comment: Jeremy Crawford unofficially agrees: ["An unseen servant is "an invisible, mindless, shapeless force" (from the spell). It's not a creature."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/943276218148966400)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that Inspiring Leader works only with creatures that can understand you. An unseen servant is "mindless", so it understands nothing.

Comment: @MarkWells That's...tricky. You give the Servant commands which seems to imply it does understand you.