# Can an Unseen Servant be attacked?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

The Unseen Servant spell creates a "shapeless force" that is not a [creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161523/can-an-unseen-servant-benefit-from-inspiring-leader/161525#161525):

> This spell creates an invisible, mindless, shapeless force that performs simple tasks at your command until the spell ends.

It already has been determined that it can't be [shoved or grappled](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191157/48603).

However, the Player Handbook (page 194) only mentions that creatures, objects, and locations might be targeted:

> **Making An Attack**
>
> Whether you’re striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure.
>
> 1. **Choose a target**. Pick a target within your attack’s range: a creature, an object, or a location.

Since the Unseen Servant is neither a creature, an object, nor a location, can it still be attacked?

Comment: Related: [What forms of damage affect an Unseen Servant?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74640/what-forms-of-damage-affect-an-unseen-servant)

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, that's why it has an armor class.

If the unseen servant couldn't be attacked, it would not have an armor class. Resolving whether or not an attack hits is the only function of armor class. Armor class is described as:

> Your Armor Class (AC) represents how well your character avoids being wounded in battle.

If the unseen servant was so good at avoiding being wounded in battle that you could not even attack it, its armor class would not be 10, it just wouldn't have one. In terms of the above description, an armor class of 10 translates to "pretty bad at avoiding being wounded".

Comment: The Unseen Servant has AC, which does imply it is intended to be attacked. However, that is not enough as a RAW (rule as written) justification - maybe the rules are written poorly and the AC ends up doing nothing.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I'm not going to tell you that the rules aren't written poorly, there is certainly lots of room for improvement in places.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, because when you take the Attack action, you can pick the location where the unseen servant is.**

As established, when you select the Attack action, you need to pick either a creature, an object, or a location.

The Unseen Servant is neither a creature or an object, so the first two options don't apply. However, you can pick a location.

Once you pick the location as the target, you can potentially hit the Unseen Servant at that location. The rules work following the "Unseen Attackers and Targets" section:

> When you Attack a target that you can’t see, you have disadvantage on the Attack roll. This is true whether you’re guessing the target’s Location or you’re targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn’t in the Location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the GM typically just says that the Attack missed, not whether you guessed the target’s location correctly.

So, you can indeed attack the Unseen Servant through attacking its location. The roll is at disadvantage because the Unseen Servant is invisible.

Comment: This answer seems to be for the question can you attack an invisible enemy, not can you attack the unseen servant.

Comment: @NautArch Are you saying it doesn't answer the original question? Because it does.