# Opportunity attacks vs unseen servant

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack

Does an unseen servant provoke an enemy's opportunity attack?

Scenario: I disarm an enemy and use my bonus action to command an unseen servant to pick up the opponent's item and carry it away somewhere.

Will the opponent get an opportunity attack against the servant?

Notes: the text for an opportunity attack specifies that the triggering creature has to be "hostile".  Given an unseen servant cannot attack, I'm thinking it cannot be hostile.

Maybe a DM may rule it can still trigger one.  If a creature (intelligent or not) was in a fight and somehow passively noticed an invisible creature walking near it, it would probably assume hostility.

But that's up to interpretation.  By RAW, is the unseen servant "safe" from opportunity attacks?

Comment: Related: Can an [Unseen Servant be attacked?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/188253/23547) and [What mechanics allow you to target an Unseen Servant?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197169/23547)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You must be able to see the creature to make an opportunity attack.

The rules for opportunity attacks state:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature **that you can see**

*Unseen servant* states:

> This spell creates an **invisible**, mindless, shapeless, Medium force

It’s invisible, so you cannot make an opportunity attack against it, because opportunity attacks require that you be able to see what you’re attacking.

#### Opportunity attacks may only target creatures.

We may also observe that the rule specified that we may attack a creature:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile **creature** that you can see

*Unseen servant* is not a creature:

> This spell creates an invisible, mindless, shapeless, Medium **force**

So even if you can see it, it isn’t a creature, so you still can’t attack it with an opportunity attack.

Comment: It's invisible, but you might be fighting someone with Truesight, or who cast See Invisible.  Or blindsight if it can see an unseen servant, although you could argue that as just a force with no physical body, sound wouldn't interact with it for blindsight.  So it's a good thing you included the second section, that it's not a creature.