# What are some use cases for attack rolls that target a location?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, targeting

In D&D 5e, a location is effectively a space in a place or a point on a map, as opposed to constituting a discrete object (a location can be a point in midair, for instance). They are defined relative to the plane of travel which that location occupies, such as a particular position on the deck of a ship, or in a cave somewhere on an oblate spheroid. In specific cases, a location might be defined *relative* to an object or creature, but mechanically speaking, each location is a space, not necessarily what's in the space.

### By RAW, attacks can target a creature, object, or *location*:

(***emphasis*** mine)

> **Making an Attack** *(PHB p193)*
> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure.
>
> 1. Choose a target. Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, ***or a location.***

Attacks targeting an *object* (including doors & walls) are well established, including the AC & HP of objects of varying material.

(Some magical structures are given damage ratings; one spell even gives its effect a standard stone AC & HP, while measuring wall area destroyed *by the inch*.)

Attacking objects (whether discrete objects or structures) seems pretty well covered, with multiple examples, & even things like Adamantine weapons that deal critical damage to objects on a hit.

Attacking *creatures* is of course the main focus of the game, so there's no shortage of examples for that.

### *However*, even though the rules state that a location can be targeted by an attack...
I haven't found any attack that would be relevant to a location!

The *only* Spell Attacks that aren't *specifically* limited to targeting creatures & objects, are Magic Stone, Flame Blade, Acid Arrow, Scorching Ray, & Mordenkainen's Sword, & based on their wording, none of those attack rolls appear to accomplish *anything* when targeting a location (*unless* a creature in a location could be hit by a spell attack targeting that location)...

### Note that specific thrown items such as a Bomb, Dynamite stick, & other items with effects that target a location, *use an Action, not an Attack roll; throwing a Bomb does not entail an Attack roll.*

For whatever reason, throwing a Net at a location to hit a creature in that location, is disputed (see the mess I made of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208056/62294)), although as @Jason_c_o has noted in their suggested answer below, **the 5e OpenSRD mentions targeting a location in order to hit an** ***unseen*** **creature.** (I guess whether that'a a good Answer is for voters to decide.)

I've been looking through magical items & weapons & features, & found absolutely *nothing* else that would target a location with an attack.

The only thing I could think of was using an item ≥10ft across to attack multiple creatures in an area, but it seems there's just no RAW to support that.

When an effect applies to creatures or objects within an area, that effect's description defines the terms of its location & extent, and specifies what creatures or objects within the area can be affected and how. There are *so many* area effects, but *none* of them involve an attack roll that would target a location!

### What are some use cases for attack rolls that target a location?

IE: What is an example of a situation wherein there is mechanical reason to target a location with an attack roll, & what are its use cases?

Comment: You state, "By RAW, attacks can target a creature, object, or location." Can you site where it says that? It might be easier to answer if we know the context in which your RAW mentions attacking location.

Comment: [Making an Attack](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Rules:Combat?expansion=0#toc_31)

Comment: Anyone answering this question should be aware that OP [is trying to prove that you can capture four creatures with one net attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208056/62294).

Comment: @ThomasMarkovwasonStrike Yes, this is a related question, thanks! Specifically in this question I'm looking for any uses for attacks that target a location (throwing a Bomb uses an Action not an Attack roll). My question here is **What attacks target a location?** So far we've only got attacks against unseen creatures. (Thanks @Jason_c_o!) *Is the only reason attacks are allowed to target locations, purely for hitting unseen foes & that's all that's there for?* Are there any other **attacks** that target **locations?**

Comment: @MivaScott also thank you, yes. Citations are good (I'd just given that same citation Jason_c_o provided in the related post ThomasMarkov linked; I got lazy! Bad questioner!) I hope the extra info helps! I'm still looking for any other attacks that target a location, besides the attacks against an unseen creature which Jason_c_o cited. I still haven't found any others, yet!? Besides hitting unseen creatures by targeting their location, can anyone provide any reference to an attack roll that targets a location???

Comment: I’ve voted to close for “needs focus”, there seem to be a couple distinct questions here. The title question and the concluding question are quite different, and I count at least one other question that could be a separate post.

Comment: Upon review, I agree; my attempts at restating actually cause it to lack clarity. I will edit this so that it's more selective in its direction of inquiry which was well answered by Jason_c_o's Answer.

Comment: I've tried to edit your question down to just the question and removed the bit that feels more like an answer. If you'd like to submit your reasoning for a certain answer, then please do so in answers where it can be voted on separately from your question.

Comment: Please don’t respond to answers or give commentary on answers in the question. The question is for the question, the answers are for answers. If you wish to endorse a particular answer, do so by upvoting, accepting, and possibly leaving a brief note as a comment on that answer.

Comment: I had *just* edited it (while retaining pertinent citations) a few seconds ago, leaving only one very clear question. Please revert your edit!

Comment: @ProphetZarquon If you feel that you want to revert, you can go ahead and so - but those aren't pertinent to the question - they are pertinent to an answer. An open question works MUCH better than trying to prove your point in a question and then asking about it. It makes it seem like you have an answer you want proven rather than an honest question about which way to go.

Comment: You now have 3 questions about this, and it very much seems like you just want agreement with your opinion, but aren't submitting it as an answer for anyone to agree with. Have you spoken with your DM about this or are you trying to use as information to bring to your DM?

Comment: Giving citations in a Question demonstrates prior research effort & avoids rehashing established rules; citations in Questions are a *good* thing. Proving or disproving would be a happy side effect of having plenty of attestation for a ruling one way or the other. I have reverted it (first time for everything) & thanks for the effort at keeping me concise even if I refused it. Is it still hard to parse?

Comment: Yes, it is. For the reasons I said above. You are trying to insert an answer into  a question, which makes it difficult to understand. But I've tried, you do you.

Comment: I *have* submitted Jason_c_o's Answer (which presented citations I'd not previously seen, so yay) as accepted. Any questions I ask on rpg.SE, are to help me clarify the game in my head & arrive at any future rulings based on good reason instead of GM fiat. (If I see that the question about Nets hitting 4 creatures, has an answer citing a strong case by RAW, I will vote to approve that too; upon my last refresh of that page, the only answer made two assertions that don't seem supported by any RAW. I like citations on dubious (& disproven) claims, sorry not sorry about that. Anything to improve?

Comment: Ohhhkay unless you're talking about a different question, I have no idea what answer you think I wanted, here, besides "any answer that shows me an attack roll that targets a location", because yes I *was* pretty sure there had to be *something* or the mechanic probably wouldn't exist. I'm glad Jason_c_o found a mechanic that uses the "target a location", but any usage would have answered my question. I just wanted to know that there *was* one!? And there was! And I'm glad because all these rules tie together & for me that's reason enough to map the interactions. What would you *add*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You're targeting a location whenever you aren't targeting an object or a creature

When you make an attack you declare its target. While some attacks may specify they only work with specific types of target, others are variable and the decision is made when the attack is declared.

You can declare an attack as targeting a location when the other two options (creature or object) do not apply.

Examples of targeting a location include, but are not limited to:

#### When you believe something in the space is *hidden* or *invisible.*

If you believe there is an invisible creature next to you, you may declare an attack on the empty space to see if you hit something. It wouldn't make sense any other way since you, as a player and in character, shouldn't know if something is occupying the space and you need to be able to declare an attack. Of course, the GM knows whether this is actually an attack on the creature or not.

> When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you’re guessing the target’s location or you’re targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn’t in **the location you targeted**, you automatically miss, but the GM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target’s location correctly. - *Unseen Attackers and Targets, 5e SRD* - Emphasis mine

You're either guessing a target's *location* **or** you're targeting a *creature* you've somehow otherwise detected.

#### When you want to throw an item into a specific square.

The DM may have you roll an attack against a location if you want to throw/shoot something, with accuracy, into a specific square or space. Perhaps near a creature or object, but not directly at them. For example: you want to throw a dagger past someone's ear. You aren't attacking them, you're attacking the space next to them.

If you want to embed your throwing axe at someone's feet or throw something next to a barrel, you're targeting a location.

In these types or situations, you wouldn't be rolling against an AC but a DC set by the DM.

Comment: That's a great note about an attack roll to hit a creature in the location targeted, when "you're guessing the target's location"! I don't know where I'd find that particular bit of (OpenSRD) text in the published books, either? ... That's incorrect about throwing bombs, grenades, & other throwable AoEs though: Every single one of them specifies that an *action* is used to throw them at a point, *not an attack roll* targeting that location... (except the Net; which once again might come down to whether a net attack targeting a location can affect a 10ft area if it's a 10ft net? Disputed?)

Comment: FYI, this question is part of OP [trying to prove that you can capture four creatures with one net attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208056/62294).

Comment: It's a question related to trying to prove or disprove that, yes.

Comment: Specifically in ***this*** question I'm looking for any uses for attacks that target a location (throwing a Bomb uses an Action not an Attack roll), & hitting a creature by targeting its space with a net is disputed (see question Re: Nets). Multiple creatures is certainly a stretch, but any citations for or against any part would be welcome. Re: this question of **what attacks target a location**; so far we've only got attacks against *unseen* creatures. Are attacks allowed to target locations, purely for unseen foes & that's all that's there for? Are there *any* other attacks that target XY?

Comment: @ProphetZarquon You asked about the net in a different question. It looks like you're trying for a specific answer you're not getting.

Comment: @ProphetZarquon An attack is an action. You use your action to make an attack roll.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I know I asked about the Net in a previous question; this is a related question & any specifics that actually cite RAW are exactly what I'm trying to get. Items which require an Action to throw\use are mechanically distinct from weapons usable as part of the Attack Action in that items like a Bomb *do not* use any Attack roll. I will clarify the question; even though the portion of your answer that was accurate has already Answered it. (I see it's corrected now, so I'm going to review & accept)

Comment: This is now a better answer than the question probably deserved, thanks! I think you would still make an Attack roll for a weapon attack against most locations, just to retain the possibility of any of an attack roll's various d20-based effects; swapping it to a DC in some cases is an intriguing suggestion which I know is used in some other mechanics, can you think of an example?

Comment: Related: some answers to [Can an Unseen Servant be attacked?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191159/23547), [What mechanics allow you to target an Unseen Servant?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/197182/23547)